# Why does Canada fund fertility treatment but not dentistry, medications or optometry?

Tags: healthcare, canada

I'm from Ontario and [OHIP funds fertility](https://www.ontario.ca/page/get-fertility-treatments). If I get the facts wrong, go ahead and just edit!

OHIP doesn't fund, if you're

1. 20-64, [optometry like annual eye exams](https://www.ontario.ca/page/what-ohip-covers#section-5).
2. over 25, [prescription medications](https://www.ontario.ca/page/learn-about-ohip-plus).
3. no matter what age, dentists.
4. no matter what age, Vitamin D tests absent special circumstances. Vitamin D deficient has been shown to cause [depression](https://www.healthline.com/health/depression-and-vitamin-d).

Are there any official statements explaining why Fertility treatment is funded ahead of the other healthcare treatments listed?

Comment: My edit has limited the question to healthcare funding, dropping the immigration vs babies section. Healthcare priorities are more likely to have sourceable answers than a wide ranging population support/healthcare/immigration discussion.

Answer (score 4):

**Sort of.  The applicable regulations specifically excludes IVF as an insured service except for one narrow circumstance.**

[Some background:](http://www.hsarb.on.ca/scripts/english/faq.asp)

> OHIP decides whether you are eligible for OHIP and whether the Plan
>   covers the health services you are claiming.
>
> You should review the reasons that OHIP gives for its decision,
>   including the relevant sections of the Health Insurance Act. If you
>   think that OHIP’s decision is wrong, you may appeal the decision to
>   the Health Services Appeal and Review Board.

Fortunately, [the decisions of the Health Services Appeal and Review Board](https://www.canlii.org/en/on/onhsarb/) are online.

[This decision from 2003](https://www.canlii.org/en/on/onhsarb/doc/2003/2003canlii67618/2003canlii67618.html) ([and also this other decision from 2013](https://www.canlii.org/en/on/onhsarb/doc/2013/2013canlii50489/2013canlii50489.html)) says:

> Section 24 of Regulation 552 provides for exclusions to s.11.2 and
>   subparagraph 23 **specifically excludes IVF as an insured service**
>   except for the narrow circumstance specified therein:
>
> 24   The following services rendered by physicians or practitioners
>   are not insured services and are not part of insured services …:
>
> (23)  In vitro fertilization other than the first three treatment
>   cycles of in vitro fertilization that are intended to address
>   infertility due to complete bilateral anatomical fallopian tube
>   blockage that did not result from sterilization.

As to **why** and how these regulations came about, [someone helpfully wrote a thesis](https://web.archive.org/web/20190923143347/https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8a4d/d36f0d6ccfef931afc9d16d95572f689fd07.pdf) which touches on the subject (this quote starts on page 124 -- there's more there than will comfortably fit in a block quote, but I urge interested parties to give it a read)

> In Ontario, in vitro fertilization was fully covered by OHIP from 1985
>   to 1994 as long as the treatment was performed in a hospital setting
>   rather than in a private clinic.
>
> [...]
>
> In the early 1990s, Ontario faced pressure from intense economic
>   restructuring and a turbulent political climate. In December 1993, the
>   New Democratic Party (NDP) government adopted the Expenditure Control
>   Plan (Bill 50) that led to much discussion in all major ministries
>   about reduction in public spending. The Health Ministry decided
>   accordingly to amend the Health Insurance Act to delist medically
>   unnecessary procedures. The province  thus decided to limit its
>   funding and to cover IVF exclusively for women with blockage of both
>   fallopian tubes, a diagnosis which represents only 1% of the cases of
>   infertility.
>
> [...]
>
> However, Ruth Grier, Minister of Health, was more cautious regarding
>   the technology. She argued that Ontario was the only province to fund
>   and that the consensus around assisted reproductive technologies was
>   to proceed with care.

To summarize:  **Ontario does not fund fertility treatments** except in an extraordinarily narrow set of circumstances.